# Password manager autofill

Tags: java, android, autofill, android-autofill-manager, password-manager

how to make an autofill app like dashlane, or lastpass on android studio. I want to make an autofill app, example facebook, It can autofill my login credentials on facebook. I want my password manager can autofill on different websites.

Comment: I think this is what you need https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/associate-apps-and-sites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Android Autofill Framework, which is available from Android 8 (API 26).
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-services